# how to create forecast data prediction interval bands

Tags: java, math, statistics, linear-regression, forecasting

I have seasonal data from which I create forecasts. The steps I perform are: deseasonalizing the data, finding the linear regression for the deseasonalized points, predicting a few points from the linear regression and adding seasonality to the predicted values to get forecast data. My input is quite sinusoidal so all works well.

The problem is that the more in the future you predict, the more prediction errors increase. I'd like to show that on a chart, but I am not sure how to calculate these errors. I was thinking something like prediction interval bands for forecast data (whatever they are called). These bands would increase the further you predict in the future.

Here are some images that show what I'm trying to do:
[sample bands image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMVot.png)
[sample bands image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD44A.png)

My **question** is what is the name for these bands? And then what libraries exists to calculate them in Java/Scala.

I use package org.apache.commons.math3.stat.StatUtils.SimpleRegression for the linear regression.

I've looked at confidence interval, but that seems to be for the data already present, not for the forecast data.

Answer (score 1):

The curves you are looking for are generically called prediction intervals or prediction bands.

I glanced at the documentation for the StatUtils package and there doesn't seem to be any support for that, although I might easily have overlooked it.

My advice is, switch to R (http://www.r-project.org) to do the statistical stuff. I'm guessing that R has functions to compute prediction bands. If you need to bolt this onto a Java program, just launch a separate process to execute R, do the computations, write an output file, and then parse the output in Java. That is a little ugly, but writing that ugly glue code is much, much easier than reimplementing R functions in Java.